# Usage of "indisposed"

Tags: word-usage

I have sometimes heard the word "indisposed" use as synonymous for "unavailable." Especially in the context of leaving a message. For example:

> "Hello. You have reached X. I am currently indisposed. Please leave a message and I will return your call soon. Thank you."

I am almost certain that the way this was used is *intended* to convey unavailability. However, the word's literal meaning is "feeling slightly unwell; averse or unwilling." Can someone clarify its usage & meaning in this context?

Comment: People who are indisposed are often unavailable.

Comment: "Indisposed" is a convenient way to say "unavailable" (or, simply, "he doesn't want to talk to you in particular") since it hints at being ill (or at the very least being currently on the pot), and it's considered impolite to pry further.  I would find it a bit suspect in an answering machine message, though.

Comment: If "indisposed" is used by itself, it usually means "I am unavailable, for reasons I am not going to tell you".  If you say you are indisposed TO something, it means you are disinclined to do it (not necessarily averse, but would rather not).  This would be considered overly formal in America.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply:

**[*Work makes me sick.*](http://www.word-detective.com/2011/10/indisposed/)**

This has become such a prevalent excuse for missing work that it has come to be understood as *not available*. [The book of Stobo Church](https://books.google.com/books?id=BB0NAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22indisposed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_mvKVJa5O4qhyQTZ5oCoBA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22indisposed%22&f=false), published in 1907, reveals how easily the word can be misinterpreted even in a context where its real definition is quite clear:

> 1770: Five times this year he was ***indisposed***; and on four
>   Sundays he preached elsewhere; nine in all marked no sermon. The
>   Sacramental Fast was held.

The vicar called in *sick*, and the records show that, but a person who doesn't know the definition could easily misconstrue that he was "*unavailable*".

In [Doors to Madame Marie](https://books.google.com/books?id=zGCUv6zGqy4C&pg=PA368&dq=%22indisposed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_mvKVJa5O4qhyQTZ5oCoBA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22indisposed%22&f=false), likewise:

> You knew when a girl had her period because, as the French put it, she
>   was "*indisposed*." It was a privilege to be *indisposed*; you could be
>   excused from anything stressful. I kept dreaming of the day when I,
>   too, could say that I was *indisposed*.

English permits pretense just as well as any language, and if we pretend long enough it becomes real to us. I rarely hear the expression used to mean "*I'm sick*," so my default interpretation is "*I'm not available*," unless the larger context indicates, "*I'm sick*."

Interestingly the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=indisposed&allowed_in_frame=0) of *indisposed* would be quite friendly to *unavailable*:

> c.1400, "*unprepared*;" early 15c., "*not in order*,"
>
> from *in*- (1) "*not*" + disposed;
>
> or else from Late Latin *indispositus* "*without order, confused*."
>
> Mid-15c. as "*diseased*;" modern sense of "*not very well*" is from 1590s.
>   A verb *indispose* is attested from 1650s but is perhaps a
>   back-formation of this.
>
> *[dispose](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dispose&allowed_in_frame=0)*
>
> late 14c., from Old French *disposer* (13c.) "*arrange, order, control,
>   regulate*" (influenced in form by *poser* "to *place*"),
>
> from Latin *disponere* "*put in order, arrange, distribute,*" from *dis*- "apart" (see
>   dis-) + *ponere* "*to put, place*" (past participle positus; see *position*
>   (n.)).

The conventional definition implies: **parts of me** are out of place. Shifting the frame of reference, the meaning becomes **I myself** am out of place.

Answer (score 7):

[The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2011/10/indisposed/) suggests:

> The emerging use of “indisposed” to mean “busy” or “unavailable” seems
>   to be an extension of the long-standing use of “indisposed” as a
>   euphemism employed in cases where the truth would be either
>   embarrassing (the person is in the bathroom, for instance) or socially
>   offensive (the person simply doesn’t wish to see or talk to you). The
>   fact that “indisposed” is a fairly snooty-sounding word has also lent
>   to its use as a sarcastic or humorous euphemism for being drunk, being
>   absent from work for another reason (such as having been fired) and
>   even for being in jail. Such humorous use of “indisposed” is fairly
>   common in films and the more literate TV sitcoms, where the humor
>   usually relies on “indisposed” being a substantial understatement of
>   the seriousness of the actual situation (e.g., the “indisposed” party
>   is dead and stuffed in the closet).

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=zGCUv6zGqy4C&pg=PA368&dq=%22indisposed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_mvKVJa5O4qhyQTZ5oCoBA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22indisposed%22&f=false

Comment: That's an equally valid _answer_.

Answer (score 1):

I indeed use it as a humorous euphemism for being unavailable as being in the bathroom, which makes me unavailable and not going to go into details.  It is a very good word and I like having the ability in todays world to use more than one liners and a vocabulary of over five letter words.  As I used to tell my children; if you don't understand a word, ASK ME or better yet look it up.  I was amazed that I had a room full of High School students that I made the statement  "That was pure propaganda."   Not one in the class knew what the word was!  I simply told one of the girls...LOOK IT UP.  She didn't know how to spell it, so I did write it on the board.

Comment: Reviewing your first Answer, I notice it would be a valuable Comment more than an answer.  The question asked about the voice greeting context.